# Set param from sql command in spite oracle is down

Tags: sql, oracle, solaris

I have Solaris machine with oracle Release 10.2.0.4.0

I have problem - I cant startup oracle

when I try to start oracle by the command:

```
       hagrp -online oracle1 -sys machine1a
```

I get:

```
      oracle1   machine1a      Y      N       PARTIAL|FAULTED
```

remark ( hagrp -clear oracle1 -sys machine1a   not help )

After checking and debug the problem  I find that oracle not start up

because wrong param - **shared_pool_size** (this param was set to 0 , while need to set this param to 2G)

So I want to set the param **shared_pool_size** to 2G but I can’t because oracle is down !!!

My question - how to set the parameter **shared_pool_size** to 2G in spite oracle is down ??? , is it possible ???

```
  su - oracle -c  "sqlplus / as sysdba"

  SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production on Mon Mar 5 12:10:44 2012

  Copyright (c) 1982, 2007, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.


  Connected to:
  Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
  With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

  SQL> alter system set shared_pool_size=2G scope=BOTH;
```

init.ora: (from my machine)

```
 grep shared_pool_size /opt/oracle/v10.2.0/srvm/admin/init.ora

       #shared_pool_size =  52428800            # INITIAL
        shared_pool_size = 67108864           # datewarehouse, transaction processing
```

Comment: What do you mean, when you say Oracle is down? Did you shut it down? Did you try connecting to Oracle with "`nolog`" option?

Comment: I can to shutdown oracle by hagrp -offline oracle1 -sys machine1a , but I cant startup oracle by hagrp -online oracle1 -sys machine1a - I get PARTIAL|FAULTED  state after 10 second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were starting from an old-style `init.ora` parameter file you could just change it in that. The `scope` in your `alter system` suggests you're using an `spfile`. You can `startup nomount` to make parameter changes, then `shutdown` again and try to start normally.

Are you sure you're connecting to the right database though? The output from your `sqlplus` command doesn't say `connected to an idle instance`, so it looks like whatever you're connected to is already running. Check where you are before running anything, and note any parameters you change first (e.g. with output from `show parameters`).

---

Based on conversation in chat...

You can create a temporary `pfile`, edit that and test starting up with it, and then when happy with the new configuration recreate your `spfile`, and finally restart from that. The steps are:

```
create pfile='/tmp/init.ora' from spfile;
-- edit /tmp/init.ora and change parms as needed 
startup pfile='/tmp/init.ora';
-- repeat as needed until successful start
create spfile=’/path/to/spfile.ora’ from pfile=’/tmp/init.ora’;
shutdown
startup 'spfile=/path/to/spfile.ora';
```

Comment: see my update - about init.ora , something not clearly , from init.ora I have already shared_pool_size = 67108864 , but the  previous value was 0 (I check that from sql - show parameter) ?

Comment: `srvm/admin/init.ora` is an example file. `init.ora` is also used shorthand for your real file. If you are using a `pfile` then you should have an `init<sid>.ora` file under `/opt/oracle/v10.2.0/dbs`, so in your case that would be called `initoracle1.ora`. It you're using an `spfile` then that may not exist, and if it does won't be used by default.

Comment: How did you use `show parameters` if the database is down? Again are you sure you're looking at the same DB? If `shared_pool_size` is set to `0` then it's being defaulted, e.g. by `sga_target`. So why do you think that specific parameter is the problem?

Comment: yes I’m  looking at the same DB , about the shared_pool_size - I get info from some troubleshooting doc and from the doc I see that need to set this param to 2G

Comment: Then the database isn't down, though it may only be allowing `SYS` to log in; what happens if you try to connect as a normal user? The parameter sounds like a red herring. Find the alert log and add the actual error it is showing to the question, and any error you get connecting as a normal user. (I'm going to guess ORA-00257, just for fun).

Comment: Hi Alex actually the DB is down - or I can’t start DB see me original question - so you said that I can set the param and then "startup nomount" please if you can give me real example for that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8542/discussion-between-alex-poole-and-eytan)

Comment: hi alex please see my last message (from chat)